# preg_replace match single but not double occurances of a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to know how to match this very example:

https://regex101.com/r/wmvSDY/1

I need to be able to replace single (also not mandatory) occurrences of `<br>` before or after the trigger but not double.

```
<br>[trigger]...[/trigger]<br><br>
```

Occurrences of `<br>` can be completely random.

```
<br><br>[trigger]...
[/trigger]<br><br>
```

Valid matches:

```
 1. **[trigger]...[/trigger]<br>**
   2. **<br>[trigger]...[/trigger]**
   3. **<br>[trigger]...[/trigger]<br>**
```

My current preg_replace looks like this:

```
"/(?:<br>)?\[trigger\](.*?)\[\/trigger\](?:<br>)?/is"
```

It only matches possible single `<br>` before or after trigger and does not care if `<br>` was part of a set or not. Please help me extend this so it does what i need.

Basically i want to match the triggers and when there is a single break before or after (but not double) to include it in the match so i can replace
**

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/J1aNCd/1 ?

Comment: Thank you, let me extend since i forgot to mention. Sometimes there are no breaks at all before the triggers and i need to match those triggers too. Basically i want to match the triggers and when there is a single break before or after (but not double) to include it in the match so i can replace.

Comment: Needs to match the entire trigger + single occurrence of <br> before or after (but not double)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/J1aNCd/4

Comment: Thank you for doing this. Updated my question with link to example text.

Comment: @splash58 Your last regex fails here: https://regex101.com/r/98j1Tt/1
when you add double <br><br>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this. the first capturing group will hold the data between tags.

`(?:(?<!<br>)<br>)?\[trigger\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/trigger\](?:<br>(?!<br>))?`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/juzalz/7/)**

**Explained**

```
(?:(?<!<br>)<br>)?  # optional <br> without a previous <br>
\[trigger\]         # trigger tag
  ([\s\S]*?)        # any character 0 or more, lazy
\[\/trigger\]       # end trigger
(?:<br>(?!<br>))?   # optional <br> without an extra <br>
```

Comment: When there are double breaks i want the match to ignore them and just match the trigger. When there is single one, i want to be included in the matched string

Comment: This regex still matches a <br> while there is another one next to it, which is something i don't want.

Comment: Fixed!, could you check again please?

Comment: Updated! In order to get the data sinide tags, just look at the second capturing group

Comment: @Zhi It matches `trigger` having two `<br>` before or after -  https://regex101.com/r/J1aNCd/5

Comment: I believe that is expected, according to what @Zhi on first comment on this answer

Comment: Julio, i accepted your answer as correct, but there is something missing:
https://regex101.com/r/PMvtXd/1
It does not match the case when there are single <br> on both sides. Can you please edit so i can close this? Thanks!

Comment: @Julio please check my previous comment.

Comment: Sure, I'll update it. I thought you needed to match exclusivelly just one of the sides

Comment: Updated! Now it should be easier since now the `<br>s` from the right won't depend on the `<br>s` from the left (and vice versa).

Comment: !YES. Awesome :)